# Permissions to/on/for something

Tags: prepositions

Sometimes I ask for permission to perform a set of authorized operations on code repository.
How can I build a sentence for such request?
I'm thinking about something like: "Provide me permissions for/on/to repository"

I want to understand whether this sentence makes sense, and if so, which preposition to use?

Comment: This question fits better on our sister site, [ell.se], a question and answer site for speakers of other languages learning English. Be sure to read their posting policy before posting your question there. [(more)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  Note that both sites have a requirement to include the results of research showing you have put effort and research into the question before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have "code repository" in your question, I'm assuming that you're in a software development environment. In that case, the de facto way to ask for permission to a code repository is to ask for "[access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_access_control#Access_approval)". For example:

> Please can I get *access to* the repository? I need to make edits to some source files.

You can also say:

> Can I get *permissions to* modify the files?

OR

> Can I get *permissions to* make edits to the files?

In a software development environment, it will be understood that you want authorization to perform certain operations on the files in question. *[Permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)* in this case will be understood to be file system permissions which are a type of access control mechanism.

The preposition to use, whether you're using *access* or *permissions*, is "*to*".

Comment: Does it depend if you are requesting permissions on a server, to update data, or for Jack in Accounting?

Comment: @ChrisMcCall I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking. Are you asking if the word to request permission would be the same if someone is trying to do something in a non-I.T. environment?

Comment: I think @Chris is saying that prepositions can vary depending on the verb and the object. There's nothing wrong with your three examples, but we might also say, "Can I request access _for_ Jack? He's new in our department." Or, "Can I get write access _on_ the production server?" It's not always _to._